# Convert CSV file into a nested JSON obj

Tags: javascript, json, nested

I am trying to convert a CSV file to a JSON nested object. I have implement the task but I have hard-coded the fields and if the CSV fields changes, I have to modify the code as well. So I am looking for a dynamic approach.

Let's say that I have already read the lines from the CSV file and I have created the following array:

```js
    var csv = ["ChapterIndex;ArticleIndex;URL;language/chapter/en;language/title/en;language/bodyText/en;language/keywords/en;language/languageCode/en;language/chapter/es;language/title/es;language/bodyText/es;language/keywords/es;language/languageCode/es",
    "1;1;www.hotmail.com;Overview-en;Article1-en;BodyText1-en;key1,key2;en;Overview-es;Article1-es;BodyText1-es;key1,key2;es",
    "1;1;www.google.com;Overview-en;Article2-en;BodyText2-en;key1,key2;en;Overview-es;Article2-es;BodyText2-ens;key1,key2;es"]
```

I want to give the following format to the JSON

```js
var obj ={
     chaterIndex:1,
     articleIndex:1,
     url:"www.test.com"
     language:[
     {  chapter:"Overvie-en",
        title:"Article1-en",
        bodyText:"bodyText-en",
        keywords:"key1,key2",
        languageCode:"en"
      },
      { chapter:"Overvie-es",
        title:"Article1-es",
        bodyText:"bodyText-es",
        keywords:"key1,key2",
        languageCode:"es"
      }]
      }
```

So far, I have achieved to complete half of the task but my logic is not going any further and I would like to ask for your assistance.

```js
var csv = ["ChapterIndex;ArticleIndex;URL;language/chapter/en;language/title/en;language/bodyText/en;language/keywords/en;language/languageCode/en;language/chapter/es;language/title/es;language/bodyText/es;language/keywords/es;language/languageCode/es",
"1;1;www.hotmail.com;Overview-en;Article1-en;BodyText1-en;key1,key2;en;Overview-es;Article1-es;BodyText1-es;key1,key2;es",
"1;1;www.google.com;Overview-en;Article2-en;BodyText2-en;key1,key2;en;Overview-es;Article2-es;BodyText2-ens;key1,key2;es"]

var attrs = csv.splice(0,1);
var articles = csv
var result = csv.map(function(row) {
  var obj = {};
  var rowData = row.split(';');
  attrs[0].split(';').forEach(function(val, idx) {
      obj = constructObj(val, obj, rowData[idx]);
 });
 return obj;
})


function constructObj(str, parentObj, data) {
  if(str.split('/').length === 1) {
    parentObj[str] = data;
    return  parentObj;
  }
  var languages = [];
  var curKey = str.split('/')[0];
  if(!parentObj[curKey])
    parentObj[curKey] = {};
  parentObj[curKey] = constructObj(str.split('/').slice(1).join('/'), parentObj[curKey], data);
  return parentObj;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please fix the errors in your snippets first so we can run them.

Comment: Great, now what is missing? What is actually the question/problem?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot get the required format of the JSON and I do not have any idea how I can achieve it. You can see the required format if you want in the initial question..

Comment: Do you have any influence on the csv layout? It's cumbersome to write the algorithm because the csv data is not "normalised".

Comment: I can convert the format of the CSV, it is up to me at all. What kind of format do you suggest me?

Comment: Use one line per language and leave the language out of the column headers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I am not sure that I understand well what do you mean. If you can show me an example I will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var csv = ["ChapterIndex;ArticleIndex;URL;language/chapter/en;language/title/en;language/bodyText/en;language/keywords/en;language/languageCode/en;language/chapter/es;language/title/es;language/bodyText/es;language/keywords/es;language/languageCode/es",
"1;1;www.hotmail.com;Overview-en;Article1-en;BodyText1-en;key1,key2;en;Overview-es;Article1-es;BodyText1-es;key1,key2;es",
"1;1;www.google.com;Overview-en;Article2-en;BodyText2-en;key1,key2;en;Overview-es;Article2-es;BodyText2-ens;key1,key2;es"]

function camelCase(str) { 
    return str 
        .replace(/\s(.)/g, function(a) { 
            return a.toUpperCase(); 
        }) 
        .replace(/\s/g, '') 
        .replace(/^.{0,3}/, function(b) { 
            return b.toLowerCase(); 
        }); 
} 

var attrs = csv.splice(0,1);
var articles = csv
var result = csv.map(function(row) {
  var obj = {};
  var rowData = row.split(';');
  attrs[0].split(';').forEach(function(val, idx) {
      obj = constructObj(val, obj, rowData[idx]);
 });
 return obj;
})


function constructObj(str, parentObj, data) {
  if(str.split('/').length === 1) {
    parentObj[camelCase(str)] = data;
    return  parentObj;
  }
  // language
  var curKey = str.split('/')[0]; 
  if(!parentObj[curKey]) {
    parentObj[curKey] = [];
    newLang = {} 
    newLang[str.split('/')[1]] = data;
    parentObj[curKey].push(newLang); 
  } else {
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < parentObj[curKey].length; i++) {
      if(Object.values(parentObj[curKey][i])[0] !== undefined && Object.values(parentObj[curKey][i])[0].includes(str.split('/').slice(2))) {
        parentObj[curKey][i][str.split('/')[1]] = data;
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      newLang = {} 
      newLang[str.split('/')[1]] = data;
      parentObj[curKey].push(newLang);
    }
  }
  return parentObj;
}

console.log(result);
```